# Loading several files as CakePHP vendors

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.4, vendor

Good day,

I have a third-party library that I would like to use with cake 2.x. Is consists of many .php files located in different nested folders. I would like to know if there is a way to import all the files with one single command e.g. make the import go through all the folders and include all the files located in them.

Thank You in advance.

Comment: You can try to implement a custom autoloader that will require files on demand. See: php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php

Comment: Also check **http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/installation/advanced-installation.html**

Comment: This third party library should have composer support. This would make things very easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is [composer](https://getcomposer.org). It's a dependency manager for php. It lets you include (and update very easily) external library into your project, and has an autoloader.

Comment: Why cakephp 3.0 includes so many files. I install fresh cake 3.8 and a simple index page includes 297 files and use 10mb of memory per single request